# Typing repetitive code(Python)

Tags: python, automation

I have been making a python program for comparing two timetables but I have had this problem a lot. The naming of variables, the text and everything else will be very repetitive, eg typing 12345123451234512345 down for each week with 5 lessons. Is there an easy way to automate this?

This is my program:

```
m1= input("M1")
m2= input('M2')
m3= input('M3')
m4= input('M4')
m5= input('M5')
t1= input('T1')
t2= input('T2')
t3= input('T3')
t4= input('T4')
t5= input('T5')
w1= input('W1')
w2= input('W2')
w3= input('W3')
w4= input('W4')
w5= input('W5')
th1= input('TH1')
th2= input('TH2')
th3= input('TH3')
th4= input('TH4')
th5= input('TH5')
f1= input('F1')
f2= input('F2')
f3= input('F3')
f4= input('F4')
f5= input('F5')
am1= input('1M1')
am2= input('1M2')
am3= input('1M3')
am4= input('1M4')
am5= input('1M5')
at1= input('1T1')
at2= input('1T2')
at3= input('1T3')
at4= input('1T4')
at5= input('1T5')
aw1= input('1W1')
aw2= input('1W2')
aw3= input('1W3')
aw4= input('1W4')
aw5= input('1W5')
ath1= input('1TH1')
ath2= input('1TH2')
ath3= input('1TH3')
ath4= input('1TH4')
ath5= input('1TH5')
af1= input('1F1')
af2= input('1F2')
af3= input('1F3')
af4= input('1F4')
af5= input('1F5')
pbm1= input("M1")
pbm2= input('M2')
pbm3= input('M3')
pbm4= input('M4')
pbm5= input('M5')
pbt1= input('T1')
pbt2= input('T2')
pbt3= input('T3')
pbt4= input('T4')
pbt5= input('T5')
pbw1= input('W1')
pbw2= input('W2')
pbw3= input('W3')
pbw4= input('W4')
pbw5= input('W5')
pbth1= input('TH1')
pbth2= input('TH2')
pbth3= input('TH3')
pbth4= input('TH4')
pbth5= input('TH5')
pbf1= input('F1')
pbf2= input('F2')
pbf3= input('F3')
pbf4= input('F4')
pbf5= input('F5')
pbam1= input('1M1')
pbam2= input('1M2')
pbam3= input('1M3')
pbam4= input('1M4')
pbam5= input('1M5')
pbat1= input('1T1')
pbat2= input('1T2')
pbat3= input('1T3')
pbat4= input('1T4')
pbat5= input('1T5')
pbaw1= input('1W1')
pbaw2= input('1W2')
pbaw3= input('1W3')
pbaw4= input('1W4')
pbaw5= input('1W5')
pbath1= input('1TH1')
pbath2= input('1TH2')
pbath3= input('1TH3')
pbath4= input('1TH4')
pbath5= input('1TH5')
pbaf1= input('1F1')
pbaf2= input('1F2')
pbaf3= input('1F3')
pbaf4= input('1F4')
pbaf5= input('1F5')
if(m1==pbm1):
    print("Same for week 1 Monday Lesson 1")
if(m2==pbm2):
    print("Same for week 1 Monday lesson 2")
if(m3==pbm3):
    print("Same for week 1 Monday Lesson 3")
if(m4==pbm4):
    print("Same for week 1 Monday Lesson 4")
if(m5==pbm5):
    print("Same for week 1 Monday Lesson 5")
if(t1==pbt1):
    print("Same for week 1 Tuesday Lesson 1")
if(t1==pbt2):
    print("Same for week 1 Tuesday Lesson 2")
if(t1==pbt3):
    print("Same for week 1 Tuesday Lesson 3")
if(t1==pbt4):
    print("Same for week 1 Tuesday Lesson 4")
if(t1==pbt5):
    print("Same for week 1 Tuesday Lesson 5")
if(w1==pbw1):
    print("Same for week 1 Wednesday Lesson 1")
if(w2==pbw2):
    print("Same for week 1 Wednesday Lesson 2")
if(w3==pbw3):
    print("Same for week 1 Wednesday Lesson 3")
if(w4==pbw4):
    print("Same for week 1 Wednesday Lesson 4")
if(w5==pbw5):
    print("Same for week 1 Wednesday Lesson 5")
if(th1==pbth1):
    print("Same for week 1 Thursday Lesson 1")
if(th2==pbth2):
    print("Same for week 1 Thursday Lesson 2")
if(th3==pbth3):
    print("Same for week 1 Thursday Lesson 3")
if(th4==pbth4):
    print("Same for week 1 Thursday Lesson 4")
if(th5==pbth5):
    print("Same for week 1 Thursday Lesson 5")
if(f1==pbf1):
    print("Same for week 1 Friday Lesson 1")
if(f2==pbf2):
    print("Same for week 1 Friday Lesson 2")
if(f3==pbf3):
    print("Same for week 1 Friday Lesson 3")
if(f4==pbf4):
    print("Same for week 1 Friday Lesson 4")
if(f5==pbf5):
    print("Same for week 2 Friday Lesson 5")
if(am1==pbam1):
    print("Same for week 2 Monday Lesson 1")
if(am2==pbam2):
    print("Same for week 2 Monday lesson 2")
if(am3==pbam3):
    print("Same for week 2 Monday Lesson 3")
if(am4==pbam4):
    print("Same for week 2 Monday Lesson 4")
if(am5==pbam5):
    print("Same for week 2 Monday Lesson 5")
if(at1==pbat1):
    print("Same for week 2 Tuesday Lesson 1")
if(at1==pbat2):
    print("Same for week 2 Tuesday Lesson 2")
if(at1==pbat3):
    print("Same for week 2 Tuesday Lesson 3")
if(at1==pbat4):
    print("Same for week 2 Tuesday Lesson 4")
if(at1==pbat5):
    print("Same for week 2 Tuesday Lesson 5")
if(aw1==pbaw1):
    print("Same for week 2 Wednesday Lesson 1")
if(aw2==pbaw2):
    print("Same for week 2 Wednesday Lesson 2")
if(aw3==pbaw3):
    print("Same for week 2 Wednesday Lesson 3")
if(aw4==pbaw4):
    print("Same for week 2 Wednesday Lesson 4")
if(aw5==pbaw5):
    print("Same for week 2 Wednesday Lesson 5")
if(ath1==pbath1):
    print("Same for week 2 Thursday Lesson 1")
if(ath2==pbath2):
    print("Same for week 2 Thursday Lesson 2")
if(ath3==pbath3):
    print("Same for week 2 Thursday Lesson 3")
if(ath4==pbath4):
    print("Same for week 2 Thursday Lesson 4")
if(ath5==pbath5):
    print("Same for week 2 Thursday Lesson 5")
if(af1==pbaf1):
    print("Same for week 2 Friday Lesson 1")
if(af2==pbaf2):
    print("Same for week 2 Friday Lesson 2")
if(af3==pbaf3):
    print("Same for week 2 Friday Lesson 3")
if(af4==pbaf4):
    print("Same for week 2 Friday Lesson 4")
if(af5==pbaf5):
    print("Same for week 2 Friday Lesson 5")
```

Do you see now?

A second attempt didn't work

```
m_input = {}
for i in range(1, 6):
    m_input['M{}'.format(i)] = input('input M{}: '.format(i))
bm_input = {}
for i in range(1, 6):
    m_input['bM{}'.format(i)] = input('input bM{}: '.format(i))
if (m_input['M1']==bm_input['bM1']):
    print("Same for week 1 Monday Lesson 1")
if (m_input['M2']==bm_input['bM2']):
    print("Same for week 1 Monday Lesson 1")
if (m_input['M3']==bm_input['bM3']):
    print("Same for week 1 Monday Lesson 1")
if (m_input['M4']==bm_input['bM1']):
    print("Same for week 1 Monday Lesson 1")
if (m_input['M5']==bm_input['bM1']):
    print("Same for week 1 Monday Lesson 1")
```

Why didn't it work?

Comment: What is repetitive, writing the program or entering in the timetables? If writing the program is repetitive, then you are not programming it right.

Comment: Copy and paste a sample of the input and the program if you want to get comments on what to do differently. As the question stands now, the only possible answer is "yes, there is a way to automate it; yes, it is easy for some, but not so much for others".

Comment: I have added my code in the original question

Comment: Whenever you find yourself repeating the same thing over and over again, there is almost certainly a better way to do it. Also called the "DRY" (*D*on't *R*epeat *Y*ourself) principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments such as

```
m1= input("M1")
m2= input('M2')
m3= input('M3')
m4= input('M4')
m5= input('M5')
```

can be shortened by using loops and storing the input in a list.

```
m_input = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    m_input.append(input('input M{}: '.format(i)))
```

You can access input number `x` at `m_input[x-1]`. Alternatively, you could use a dictionary to create pairs of names and input values.

```
m_input = {}
for i in range(1, 6):
    m_input['M{}'.format(i)] = input('input M{}: '.format(i))
```

Now you can access `M1` at `m_input['M1']`, `M2` at `m_input['M2']` and so on.

Comment: Using `"M{}".format(i+1)` is more readable and doesn't require explicitly casting the `i+1`.

Comment: Please check my original question for the code I made from this syntax and please explain why it didn't work.

Comment: @SamRob85 The issue with your new code is the following: in the second `for` loop, you are storing the `bM` values in the `m_input` dictionary. Change `m_input['bM{}'.format(i)] = input('input bM{}: '.format(i))` to `bm_input['bM{}'.format(i)] = input('input bM{}: '.format(i))`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using an array instead of all the variables and a for loop for adding data:

```
for i in range(5)
    myarray.append("m" + str(i+1))
```